# Is there some way to define an Enum in haskell that wraps around?

Tags: haskell

Consider I was designing a Monopoly game:

```
data Board = GO | A1 | CC1 | A2 | T1 | R1 | B1 | CH1 | B2 | B3 | 
  JAIL | C1 | U1 | C2 | C3 | R2 | D1 | CC2 | D2 | D3 | 
  FP | E1 | CH2 | E2 | E3 | R3 | F1 | F2 | U2 | F3 | 
  G2J | G1 | G2 | CC3 | G3 | R4 | CH3 | H1 | T2 | H2
  deriving (Show, Enum, Eq)
```

I want:

```
succ H2 == GO
```

But instead:

```
*** Exception: succ{Board}: tried to take `succ' of last tag in enumeration
```

Is there a typeclass for expressing an enumeration that wraps around?

Comment: Huh, `Enum`. You just need to write your own instead of deriving it automatically.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest option is to make Board an instance of `Bounded`  (can be auto derived as well), and use the following helper functions:

```
next :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
next = turn 1

prev :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
prev = turn (-1)

turn :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => Int -> a -> a
turn n e = toEnum (add (fromEnum (maxBound `asTypeOf` e) + 1) (fromEnum e) n)
    where
      add mod x y = (x + y + mod) `rem` mod
```

Example Use:

```
> next H2
G0
> prev G0
H2
> next F1
F2
```

(inspired by the the thread at http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg37258.html ).

If you really need to use `succ` and `pred` instead, I don't believe there is any laws regarding implementations of `Enum` such that `succ (succ x) /= x` for all `x` (even though that is how most work). Therefore you could just write a custom implementation of `Enum` for your type that exhibits the wraparound you desire:

```
instance Enum Board where
  toEnum 0 = G0
  toEnum 1 = A1
  ...
  toEnum 40 = H2
  toEnum x = toEnum (x `mod` 40)

  fromEnum G0 = 0
  fromEnum A1 = 1
  ...
  fromEnum H2 = 40
```

That is very tedious to implement though. Also, the type shouldn't also implement `Bounded` when using a circular definition of `Enum`, as that breaks a rule regarding `Bounded` that `succ maxBound` should result in a runtime error.

Comment: I recommend against making succ maxBound = minBound; the Bounded typeclass explicitly says that succ maxBound should result in a runtime error.

Comment: This still doesn't let you do, say `[H1 .. A1]`, which should logically be equal to `[H1, T2, H2, GO, A1]`.

Comment: @Edward: The second solution doesn't have Board an instance of Bounded, so that problem doesn't occur. I'll make that more explicit that the type cannot be Bounded when implementing Enum that way in the answer though.

Comment: Ah, I suppose, then, that this is OK. :-)

Answer (score 30):

A simpler solution than nanothief:

```
nextBoard :: Board -> Board
nextBoard H2 = GO
nextBoard t = succ t
```

I don't think you'll be able to use Enum directly for what you want, but this solution quickly wraps it to form the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but I just had this problem and I solved it this way.

```
data SomeEnum = E0 | E1 | E2 | E3
               deriving (Enum, Bounded, Eq)

-- | a `succ` that wraps 
succB :: (Bounded a, Enum a, Eq a) => a -> a 
succB en | en == maxBound = minBound
         | otherwise = succ en

-- | a `pred` that wraps
predB :: (Bounded a, Enum a, Eq a) => a -> a
predB en | en == minBound = maxBound
         | otherwise = pred en
```

The solution derives both `Enum` and `Bounded` but avoids abusing `pred` and `succ` as suggested.

Incidently, I found that having

```
allSomeEnum = [minBound..maxBound] :: [SomeEnum]
```

can be useful. That requires `Bounded`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a disgusting way to define an efficient wrapping `Enum` instance without doing much by hand.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

import GHC.Exts (Int (..), tagToEnum#, dataToTag# )

-- dataToTag# :: a -> Int#
-- tagToEnum# :: Int# -> a
```

Now you can write

```
data Board = ... deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded)

instance Enum Board where
  fromEnum a = I# (dataToTag# a)

  toEnum x | x < 0 || x > fromEnum (maxBound :: Board) =
    error "Out of range"
  toEnum (I# t) = tagToEnum# t
  succ x | x == maxBound = minBound
         | otherwise == toEnum (fromEnum x + 1)
  pred x ....
```

Answer (score 2):

With `Eq` you can check if it's the last element.

```
next :: (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> a
next = bool minBound <$> succ <*> (/= maxBound)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the typeclass and instance below. You would just need to also derive `Bounded`

```
class (Eq a, Enum a, Bounded a) => CyclicEnum a where
  cpred :: a -> a
  cpred d
    | d == minBound = maxBound
    | otherwise = pred d
  
  csucc :: a -> a
  csucc d
    | d == maxBound = minBound
    | otherwise = succ d
    

instance CyclicEnum Board
```

The example is from the amazing book: [Haskell in Depth](https://www.manning.com/books/haskell-in-depth)