# Access the next element of 'data'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have defined this data `data MonthData = Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec deriving ( Eq, Show, Enum, Ord )`

**How can I implicitly access an element given its previous one?**

For instance, I have a *Jan* and I want to access to *Feb* without explicitly typing *Feb*

Cheers

Answer (score 10):

You asked the compiler to infer an `Enum` instance, so

```
>>> :t succ 
succ :: Enum a => a -> a
>>> succ Jan
Feb
```

Note however

```
>>> succ Dec 
*** Exception: succ{MonthData}: tried to take `succ' of last tag in enumeration
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684049/is-there-some-way-to-define-an-enum-in-haskell-that-wraps-around. Maybe add Neil Brown's solution from that thread as `nextMonth`.

Answer (score 1):

You use the class function for `Enum`: [succ](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:succ).